# Passing javascript variable to gsp g:link tag

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

I am looking to pass a javascript variable in the id field of a g:link gsp tag but don't know how to do it. If I am going about this the wrong way let me know.

Here is what I have:

- a table which each row has the id I want to pass in the g:link
- javascript that onClick of the table row sets a javascript variable with the value of the row id

```
    <r:script disposition="head">
      var data = -1;
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#${tableId} tr').click(function (event) {
          data = $(this).attr('id');
        });
      });
    </r:script>
```

- then i want to pass the javascript `data` variable to a g:link

```
    <li><g:link controller="filterIntraday" action="show" id="??????">View</g:link></li>
```

I can't get this to work.  How do I set the javascript variable in the gsp tag.  Or what is another way to go about passing a client side variable in the g:link tag ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about changing "href" attribute inside event function:

```
function (event) {
    data = $(this).attr('id');
    $("link-selector").attr("href", "${createLink(controller: 'filterIntraday', action: 'show')}/" + data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergei. This is a good suggestion and it solves the problem about being able to add a javascript variable to the end of a gsp generated link. However it breaks the the way I had the code organized.  I had the links all in a template.  With this method I would need to update all links in the javascript click.  Iwanted to just update a javascript variable and place that variable in the template. I hope this was not too confusing of an explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set the id in the gsp tag because the tag is already processed. What you can do is change the `href` of the generated html. To do that you need to assign an id to the `<a>` element.

```
<li><g:link controller="filterIntraday" action="show" elementId="linkToFilter">View</g:link></li>
```

This will create something like:

```
<li>a<a href='yourapp/filterIntraday/show' id="linkToFilter" /></li>
```

Then in your javascript you can change the href:

```
data = $(this).attr('id');
$link = $('#linkToFilter');
$link.attr('href', $link.attr('href')+'/'+data);
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation and details. basically the same idea as Sergei's comment but more detailed.